# express.js - Session access middleware not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session

I'm trying to create a middleware using JS, Express and Session where access to certain pages are blocked depending on whether a session exists. This is what I've tried:

```
function validateAdminLogin(req,res,next) {
  if(req.session.adminId) {
    next()
  } else {
      res.redirect('/signIn')
  }
}

app.all('/admin/*',validateAdminLogin,function(req,res,next){
  next()
})
```

After trying to access any of the pages under /admin with no sessions active, the code is still accessing the /admin files.

Comment: "access /admin... with no sessions active, the code is still re-directing to /signIn." Isn't this the expected behaviour?

Comment: @DanielReinoso you are correct... apologies, I meant accessing the admin files. I updated the question.

Comment: You can also do `app.all('/admin/*', validateAdminLogin)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to add the snippet below before any /admin endpoint.

```
function validateAdminLogin(req,res,next) {
  if(req.session.adminId) {
    next()
  } else {
      res.redirect('/signIn')
  }
}

app.all('/admin/*',validateAdminLogin,function(req,res,next){
  next()
})
```

Example:

```
app.get('/admin/test2', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Not affected by middleware')
})

app.all('/admin/*', validateAdminLogin)

app.get('/admin/test', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Affected by middleware')
})
```